# debug APK to release APK without recompiling

Tags: android, apk

I have been given an APK file from my mobile developers and I need to upload this to the store. It says, you need to compile it in release mode. Is there a way in which i can do that to the apk, get it to become in release mode and sign it with a key, without having to get the developers to actually re-compile?

If no, can I extract an apk file, put it in ant and recompile to release mode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe you can do this without recompiling and resigning.  You need to change the AndroidManifest and re-sign it using the same key as was used to upload it the first time if it was previously uploaded.

Comment: No this is its first time that it's going to get uploaded. So I can't use those apk extractor tools and then use the output to recompile in release mode??

Comment: Actually, you can, but it is more easily done with the developer just rebuilding and resigning it, why not do that?  It is a more complicated process for you to do this.

Comment: I needed to get the app in the store that instance and the developers had 'gone to sleep' ... so I was wondering.. but heck, didn't happen so didn't happen!

Comment: Thanks for the votes - of course developers never really sleep, that is just when they are away from their computer :)

Comment: I'm a developer my self.. I just didn't have the source code for the project! haha, developers definitely need their sleep. It's a fun way to look at it, as 'we never sleep', but sleep is of paramount importance. 

In fact, on numerous occasions at 2 in the night, I've sent back my developers home telling them to come next day at 1.00 PM and spend the mornings with their families. It's ok when you're still single, but when you have a family.. you need to be home!